# How to assign a specific order and variable to each cell in a dataTable column according to other cells

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datatables, epplus

I'm a super newbie who started this project on WPF (.NET) around two weeks ago without knowing a single thing about programming. My project is complex (for me, you know, being a newbie) and I've been stuck in its final part for days.

I'll try to concisely resume what it does but I tend to get carried away while explaining things.

My program reads an excel sheet containing more than 15.000 rows and 6 columns using OfficeOpenXml (I tried with the Microsoft Interop assembly but it was too slow), stores those values in a dataTable and presents to the user listboxes to filter those values. So I have Regions, Sellers, Stores, Product Groups, Products and Selling Percentages as columns. The program filters distinct values from the Regions column to populate a listbox and the user makes a selection. Then it filters distinct values from the Sellers column that have in its row the selected value from the Region, and populate a new listbox. Then again for the Stores column. Then, I have three buttons meant to separate the three different product groups. Right now I am only using one of them to run tests. Once the user clicks that button, the program will filter every selected region, seller, store and product group that the user chose, and list the products that match those selections. It will then read the percentages in its adjacent column, and for values equal or above 75% it will store the product value as "1", for equal or under 74% and equal or above 25% it will store the product value as "2", and for equal or under 25% it will store the product value as "3". Then I'm supposed to show those values in a messagebox, without spaces.

I know that after filtering certain values until I get to the that button's click event, I have 102 values in the percentage cell. Being 16 cells containing a value above 75% (which should translate to number 1 based on my code), 28 cells containing a value between 25 and 74 (which should translate to number 2 based on my code), and 60 values under 25% (which should translate to 3 based on my code).

Currently in my code none of the other values are displaying correctly. According to my numbers and my current code the output should be "11111111111111112222222222222222222222222222333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333". but all I'm getting is "3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333".

I have tried so many things, but I lack the knowledge to find out where is the problem.

If anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong in this code I'd appreciate a lot! Here is the button click event and other relevant code:

```
        public class ProductInfo
        {
            public string Product { get; set; }
            public double Percentage { get; set; }
            public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
        }

        private void BtnSi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the selected region from the RegList listbox.
            string selectedRegion = RegList.SelectedItem.ToString();

            // Get the selected seller from the SelList listbox.
            string selectedSeller = SelList.SelectedItem.ToString();

            // Get the selected client from the clientListBox listbox.
            var selectedClient = ((dynamic)clientListBox.SelectedItem).Client;

            // Get the distinct values from the "product" column that have in its row the selected values from the RegList, the SelList, the clientListBox list, and that have "IDEAL" in the "mix" column.
            var distinctProducts = MyData.ExcelData.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row.Field<string>("region") == selectedRegion)
                .Where(row => row.Field<string>("seller") == selectedSeller)
                .Where(row => row.Field<string>("client").Contains(selectedClient))
                .Where(row => row.Field<string>("mix") == "IDEAL")
                .Select(row => row.Field<string>("product"))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

            // Create a list to store the product numbers
            List<string> productNumbers = new List<string>();

            // Loop through the distinct products
            foreach (var product in distinctProducts)
            {
                // Get the percentage values for this product
                var percentages = MyData.ExcelData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("region") == selectedRegion)
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("seller") == selectedSeller)
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("client").Contains(selectedClient))
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("mix") == "IDEAL")
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("product") == product)
                    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("percentage"))
                    .ToList();

                // Determine the product number based on the percentage values
                string productNumber = "0";
                double maxPercentage = percentages
                    .Select(p => double.Parse(p.TrimEnd('%')))
                    .Max();

                if (maxPercentage > 75.0)
                {
                    productNumber = "1";
                }
                else if (maxPercentage >= 25.0 && maxPercentage <= 75.0)
                {
                    productNumber = "2";
                }
                else if (maxPercentage < 25.0)
                {
                    productNumber = "3";
                }

                // Add the productNumber to the list for each product
                productNumbers.Add(productNumber);
            }

            

            // Join the product numbers into a single string
            string message = string.Join("", productNumbers);

            // Display the product numbers in a message box
            MessageBox.Show($"Product Numbers: {message}");
        }
```

As I said I'm a newbie so I'm not even sure if what I tried is correct, but I tried moving the percentage convertion code in and out of the foreach loop, tried displaying the product column values to see if the problem is with them (it isn't, they show up just fine), tried using lists, dictionaries, new datatables, etc. Nothing works. Up until yesterday all I was getting was a blank messagebox, and I managed to fix it out of pure luck, that now it actually display values, but still incorrectly.
I did try googling relentlessly but I don't really understand much of what I find. Usually every article I find that might solve my problem is explained in a very advanced way and I end up making more mistakes than fixes in my code. I tried asking for ChatGPT and Google Bard to help me but they complicate more than help, too. My last resort is human's knowledge explained as if it was for a 5 year old, lol.
I am confirming that none of the posts in Stackoverflow answers my question because I simply do not understand any of them.

Comment: Hard to tell from the amount of code you have posted.  You may want to post either more of it or link to a working demo project.  Just by looking at it, what is the value of `maxperecentage`?  If I had to guess, it is probably always `0`.  Set a breakpoint after that `Parse` to see.   It could be there is nothing coming back from that field.

Comment: Noone has the time to read so much. You need to provide the minimum amount of information needed for someone to be able to help you. And if you have any monologue, add it at the end and not the beginning so our patience is not run out after just reading that. Although best not to add it at all.